# How do I ensure the entire parent control is visible when a compound XAML control is Tab Selected?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a compound XAML control. It looks like this:

```
<UI:CompoundControl 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Dynamics="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.UI" Height="Auto" >
    <Stackpanel Orietnation="Vertical">
        <TextArea x:Name="lblTop" DockPanel.Dock="Left">Label</TextArea >
        <TextArea x:Name="lblBottom" DockPanel.Dock="Left">Label</TextArea >
    </Stackpanel >
</UI:CompoundControl>
```

When the application runs, there is a UIElementCollection of these `CompoundControl`s, which displays them in a scrollable list.

When I press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, the application moves focus to the next TextArea in sequence, scrolling the view to do so. However, it only scrolls to show the *focused* control, so I'm running into an issue where pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't show the entirety of the `CompoundControl`, only the upper half.

Is there some attribute I can set so that the automatic scrolling shows the entire control, instead of simply the upper half?

Comment: Set "CanContentScroll" property of a ScrollViewer to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way to make it work by responding to the top control's "GotFocus" event. `scrollViewer` in this case is the parent ScrollViewer that the compound control gets added to.

```
private const int SCROLL_PADDING = 10;
private void lblTop_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (scrollViewer == null) return;
            FrameworkElement element = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
            var transform = element.TransformToVisual(scrollViewer);
            var positionInScrollViewer = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

            //Scrolls the viewer down far enough to see this control + the control directly below it.
            if (positionInScrollViewer.Y < 0 ||
                positionInScrollViewer.Y + SCROLL_PADDING > scrollViewer.ViewportHeight)
            {
               scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset +
                    positionInScrollViewer.Y - SCROLL_PADDING);
            }


        }
```

This will scroll the ScrollViewer past the entirety of the compound control, but only if the top part of the compound control is off, or nearly-off, the screen.